# How can I account for period (a. m. /p. m.) using strftime?

Tags: python

I need to perform the following task:

```
from datetime import datetime
date_string = '25/9/19 8:59 p. m.'
format = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M %p'
my_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)

# This prints '2019-09-25 08:59 PM'
print my_date.strftime(format)
```

By this page:
https://docs.python.org/3/library/time.html#time.strftime

I know that %p is Locale’s equivalent of either AM or PM. However, this dateformat is "p. m." and not "PM". So I have to take into account the dots.

Thank you for the very much needed help!

Comment: You can always do a simple substitution: `date_string.replace("p. m.", "PM").replace("a. m.", "AM")`

Comment: What is the issue, exactly? Have you tried anything, done any research? Please see [ask], [help/on-topic]. Also, why were there a bunch of seemingly irrelevant tags?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You might want to look into regex for pre-processing your dates before formatting them.

```
import re

# quick example for how to substitute with regex if you're looking at one string at a time
print(re.sub("p. m.", "PM", '25/9/19 8:59 p. m.'))
print(re.sub("a. m.", "PM", '25/9/19 8:59 a. m.'))

# some type of iterable of these dates with bad am/pm characters
list_of_dates = ['25/9/19 8:59 p. m.', '25/9/19 8:59 a. m.', '25/9/19 8:59 a. m.', '25/9/19 8:59 p. m.']

# you can "pre-compile" your regex patterns so they're faster to work with
pattern_am = re.compile("a. m.")
pattern_pm = re.compile("p. m.")

# then you can use list comprehension to apply the regex pattern substitution to the entire list/series
corrected_dates = [pattern_am.sub("AM", x) for x in list_of_dates]
corrected_dates = [pattern_pm.sub("PM", x) for x in corrected_dates]
```

Others have correctly pointed out using `.replace()` string method. You can also wrap that into a list comprehension as well. **My assumption here is that you have more than a single date that you need to "fix."** If so, I would do some research on list comprehensions. For something quick like this, they tend to make your code more readable than for-loops.

```
corrected_dates = [x.replace('a. m.', 'AM') for x in list_of_dates] 
corrected_dates = [x.replace('p. m.', 'PM') for x in corrected_dates]
```

Comment: Using regex for plain str replacement is like using cannon to hit the fly.

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski fair enough! I agree that str.replace() is simpler and better solves this specific problem.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `replace()` to update the string before parsing it:

```
from datetime import datetime

date_string = '25/9/19 8:59 p. m.'
date_string = date_string.replace('p. m.', 'PM').replace('a. m.', 'AM')
format = '%d/%m/%y %I:%M %p'
my_date = datetime.strptime(date_string, format)
```

For a 12 hour clock, you'll need to represent hours with %I instead of %H.

Answer (score 0):

`p. m.` is not commonly used abbreviation. You need to normalize your date string prior passing to  `strftime()` i. e. using plain string replace:

```
date_string = date_string.replace('a. m.', 'am').replace('p. m.', 'pm')
```